# Render props method without nesting dom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

In essence I have the following inside a react **functional** component:

```
<div className="content">
<div className="filters">
    <MyFilter1 data={data}>
        {(filter1Data) => {
            return <MyFilter2 data={filter1Data}>
                {(finalData) => {
                    return <div className="final-data">{finalData}</div>
                }}
            </MyFilter2>
        }}
    </MyFilter1>
</div>

<div className="filtered" />
```

I am using multiple filters with the render children paradigm to get the final data. But for (admittedly frustrating) styling reasons, I would like to render the final data in a div **outside** of the filters location (inside the 'filtered' div in this case). How can I do this? Is my approach wrong? Is the 'filter with render children' the wrong approach?

I have tried:

React portal with createRef(), in essence the problem ends up being that the ref is not available yet when the 'finalData' function is called.

Edit:

The filter components themselves are very complicated but I can give a couple examples. The data I'm filtering is a simple object with 12ish properties. One of the filters is implemented as a series of checkboxes determining which properties of the data I want to display (necessary as a separate component because of the number of fields). One of the properties on the data is a price, and another filter is a price range 'dialer', that specifies the price range to display ( aka exclude data points outside the range).

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? In other words, what are you using two nested components with render props for? It would help if you posted the code inside `MyFilter1` and `MyFilter2`.

Comment: The general idea is to be able to pass a set of data through multiple different filters, and then display the resulting data (the filters filter the data in different ways). To me, the most readable approach to that was the render-children way

Comment: If there is a better approach to that though I am also open to that

Comment: It sounds like something simpler would work, but it's unclear without seeing what you're doing inside those 2 components.

Comment: It is currently two... but it's going to grow to potentially upwards of 5 or 6. I want a simple 'assembly line' I can pass them through

Comment: Could you update your question with the component implementations?